# Beautiful Soup: Get text data from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is my html code now I want extract data from following html code using beautiful soup

```
<tr class="tr-option">
<td class="td-option"><a href="">A.</a></td>
<td class="td-option">120 m</td>
<td class="td-option"><a href="">B.</a></td>
<td class="td-option">240 m</td>
<td class="td-option"><a href="">C.</a></td>
<td class="td-option" >300 m</td>
<td class="td-option"><a href="">D.</a></td>
<td class="td-option" >None of these</td>
</tr>
```

here is my beautiful soup code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for option in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':"td-option"}):
    print option.text
```

output of above code:

```
A.
120 m
B.
240 m
C.
300 m
D.
None of these
```

but I want following output

```
A.120 m
B.240 m
C.300 m
D.None of these
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `find_all` returns a list of options, you can use list comprehensions to obtain the answer as you expect

```
>>> a_list = [ option.text for option in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':"td-option"}) ]
>>> new_list = [ a_list[i] + a_list[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a_list),2) ]
>>> for option in new_list:
...     print option
... 
A.120 m
B.240 m
C.300 m
D.None of these
```

**What it does?**

- `[ a_list[i] + a_list[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a_list),2) ]` Takes adjacent elements from `a_list` and appends them.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc) 
options = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': "td-option"}) 
texts = [o.text for o in options] 
lines = [] 
# Add every two-element pair as a concatenated item
for a, b in zip(texts[0::2], texts[1::2]): 
    lines.append(a + b)
for l in lines:
    print(l)
```

Gives

```
A.120 m
B.240 m
C.300 m
D.None of these
```